# gnome-control-center not found but installed

Tags: apt, gnome, package-management, desktop-environments

On Ubuntu 18.04, I recently installed Pantheon but then removed it and the PPAs using the appropriate method. However it now seems that the settings menu won't open, either from GUI or terminal. When I run `gnome-control-center` I get "Command not found but can be installed with..." and when I try to install it, I get "gnome-control-center is already the newest version". What's going on here? I already tried re-installing the `ubuntu-desktop` and `apt dist-upgrade`, `apt autoremove` and `apt clean` and still not luck.

Answer (score 5):

It turns out that doing `apt remove gnome-control-center` and `apt install gnome-control-center` fixes this.

However when launching from terminal a Gtk message "Failed to load module 'pantheon-filename-module'" appears, so perhaps indicating an incomplete or incorrect clean-up.